# Application terminated after try to add recyclerView

Tags: android

I just want to add recyclerView in my android app. After I added recyclerView, application crash after splash screen.

Splash.java

```
public class Splash extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Intent loginintent = new Intent(Splash.this,Home.class);
            Splash.this.startActivity(loginintent);
            Splash.this.finish();

        }
    },3000);
}
```

}

Home.java

```
public class Home extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

private  TabLayout tabLayout;
private  ViewPager viewPager;
private  int[] tabIcons = {
        R.drawable.home,
        R.drawable.faculty };

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    //private Toolbar toolbar;


    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    setupViewPager(viewPager);

    tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

    setupTabIcons();


}

private void setupTabIcons() {
    tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setIcon(tabIcons[0]);
    tabLayout.getTabAt(1).setIcon(tabIcons[1]);
}
private  void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager){

    ViewPagerAdapter adapterCustom = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    adapterCustom.addFrag(new HomeTab(),"Home");
    adapterCustom.addFrag(new NoticeTab(),"Notice");
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapterCustom);
}


@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.home, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        Intent information = new Intent(Home.this,Information.class);
        startActivity(information);
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.home) {
        // Handle the camera action
    } else if (id == R.id.faculty) {

    } else if (id == R.id.intdetail) {

        Intent instDetail = new Intent(Home.this,About.class);
        startActivity(instDetail);

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

    } else if (id == R.id.logout) {
        SharedPreferences myPrefs = getSharedPreferences("Activity", MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = myPrefs.edit();
        editor.clear();
        editor.commit();
        AppState.getSingleInstance().setLoggingOut(true);

        //Log.d(TAG, "Now log out and start the activity login");
        Intent intent = new Intent(Home.this, Login.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();

    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
```

}
Here I am giving Logcat of of this application

> E/lowmemorykiller: Error writing /proc/22911/oom_score_adj; errno=22 03-12 21:09:45.483 1501-1671/?

E/InputDispatcher: channel 'a154656 com.ajoy.gdp/com.ajoy.gdp.Home (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed! 03-12 21:09:45.483 1501-671/?

E/InputDispatcher: channel '26aeadf com.ajoy.gdp/com.ajoy.gdp.Splash (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed! 03-12 21:09:45.499 2637-2836/? 
E/WtProcessController: Error pid or pid not exist

Comment: please show your code in which you try this thing @Ajoy

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Have you tried anything so far? StackOverflow isn't a free code-writing service, and expects you to [**try to solve your own problem first**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592). Please update your question to show what you have already tried, showcasing the specific problem you are facing in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For further information, please see [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [**tour of the site**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Comment: The first table i added is actually table of pnr detail.

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…”)` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or **any** user data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: I have use $_POST, $_GET method in another php file but in this case i have to use get method for filling all text box selecting one. It actually nested form if send this again to another file .

Comment: Is it possible to run a mysql query and use where clause by using Javascript depend on what we insert in textbox?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?php
    $sql = "SELECT * from students where id =".$id;
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
?>

<input type="text" name="firstName" id="firstName" value="<?php echo $row['first_name']; ?>">
<input type="text" name="lastName"  id="lastName" value="<?php echo $row['last_name']; ?>">
<input type="text" name="age"  id="age" value="<?php echo $row['age']; ?>">
```